# How can I add interactive python console to my website?

Tags: customization

I'd like to create an educational website where I would like people to be able to run Python console from an interpreter window and also be able to modify that code in the window and run it again to see how the results vary.

In the link below there is a good example of this:

https://www.safaribooksonline.com/oriole/saf-generative-adversarial-networks-for-beginners

I know I can create a Jupyter notebook and embed it with an iFrame, but it only displays the static version. I want to find a way to run the kernel server- or client-side and let people play around.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the example link you provided uses O'Reilly's open source project Thebe: https://github.com/oreillymedia/thebe

The readme in the repo provides some instructions to get it set up. Hope that helps!